# Pass "is null" as parameter to a query with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I am using sqlsrv driver with PHP 5.3.27. How can I pass "is null" as a parameter to a query.
So instead

```
SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE name IS NULL
```

I could use

```
SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE name = ?
```

Comment: whats wrong with using IS NULL?

Comment: In some cases I need to check if it is null in others - if it is some value. And I wanted to do it with one query with parameters.

Comment: have a look at my query and tell me whether that serves ur purpose or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though of another way to do that myself

```
SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE ISNULL(name,-1)=?
```

If you're sure that you will never use '-1' as a condition, this will work. Just use your parameter when you need a value and '-1' when you need "IS NULL".
But I guess there is no way to pass "is null" as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Well... What prevents you from writing an if/else clause?

```
if($i_need_a_value) {
    $query = 'SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE name = ?';
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE name IS NULL';
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if it is possible.
If not - I guess that would be the way to do that.

Comment: well, right now I'm using this solution
And I guess answer to my question is that I can't

Comment: to check for NULL values you need `IS NULL` (as `= NULL` doesn't get you the result you'd expect, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for explanation). So you either need this simple clause or a relatively complex query. Just for simplicity's sake I would go for a solution like this. You could also insert operator, like this: `$operator = '='; $query = 'SELECT row_id FROM table WHERE name '. $operator .' ?';`

Answer (score 0):

u can check for the particular column if it is null or it contains somevalue by the following query.

```
select row_id 
from table 
where (name IS NULL) or (name IS NOT NULL && name<>'');
```

Comment: note to prevent confusion: `<>` is equivalent to `!=` when using in a where statement

Comment: <> means not equal to as far as i know @giorgio:p

Comment: That's not what I need.
When page is loaded I either need to see only "NULL" values or only specific values.
I do not want them both

Comment: check my edit,i think this is wat u want @MaiorovYury

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement to work around the nullability issue. A neat trick is to use a join with a single-row dummy query to avoid having to bind your value twice:

```
SELECT row_id 
FROM   table
JOIN   (SELECT ? AS param) dummy
WHERE  (name IS NULL AND param IS NULL) OR name = param
```